# Authenticating with Acts As Follower and Devise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, controller

I'm using Devise with Acts As Follower. The setup is simple where users can follow celebrities. What I'd like to do is only allow signed in users to follow/unfollow celebrities. If a non-registered user clicks the follow button I'd like them to be redirected to the registration screen. I'm aware of Devise's `before_action :authenticate_user!` but having a hard time figuring out how to trigger this as a clickable event for my `follow`/`unfollow` actions in my celebrities controller.

Where my current code falls short is that it only works if the `current_user` is signed in. If not a receive the error: `undefined method 'following?' for nil:NilClass`. I'd like to know know how I could fix this and if there's anything that could be improved as my rails code and javascript's toggle functionality.

**Celebrity Show View**

```
<% if current_user.following?(@celebrity) %>
    <%= link_to "Unfollow", unfollow_celebrity_path, method: :post, class: "unfollow", remote: true %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Follow", follow_celebrity_path, method: :post, class: "follow", remote: true %>
<% end %>

<%= render _toggle.html.erb %>
```

**Toggle Button Partial**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('a').click(function() {
            if ($(this).text() == "Unfollow") {
                $(this).html("<%=  escape_javascript( link_to 'Follow', follow_celebrity_path, method: :post, remote: true) %>").addClass('follow')
            } else {
                $(this).html("<%=  escape_javascript( link_to 'Unfollow', unfollow_celebrity_path, method: :post, remote: true) %>").addClass('unfollow')
            }
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

**Celebrities Controller**

```
...

def follow
  @celebrity = Celebrity.find(params[:id])

  if current_user
    current_user.follow(@celebrity)
  end   
end

def unfollow
  @celebrity = Celebrity.find(params[:id])

  if current_user
    current_user.stop_following(@celebrity)
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
resources :celebrities do
  member do
    post :follow
    post :unfollow
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix it (Update your if condition):

```
<% if current_user.present? && current_user.following?(@celebrity) %>
```

Regarding User login redirect, this should work(sorry I don't have time to test):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $('a').click(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == "Unfollow") {
            $(this).html("<%= escape_javascript( link_to 'Follow', follow_artist_path, method: :post, remote: true) %>").addClass('follow').removeClass('unfollow');
        } else {
            $(this).html("<%= escape_javascript( link_to 'Unfollow', unfollow_artist_path, method: :post, remote: true) %>").addClass('unfollow').removeClass('follow');
        }
    })

    $(".follow,.unfollow").bind("ajax:error", function(data, xhr, status, error) {
        if (xhr.status == 401) {
            window.location.replace("<%= new_user_session_path %>");
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: That seemed to fix the the view code still need a way to redirect non-registered users to the sign up page if the try click the follow button. I tried using the before action `authenticate_user!, only: [:follow, :unfollow]` but it didn't do anything.

Comment: Since your request is an Ajax call, it can not redirect the user, you will have to manually  check the response status of the ajax call and redirect the user to login if he is not logged in.

Comment: What would be the best way to do so? I'm not the greatest when it comes to Ajax. In addition to marking this answer as correct I can definitely award a bonus point to explain things further if its not too much to ask.

Comment: @CarlEdwards Please check my updated answer. I'm checking the response status of the AJAX call returned and if its unauthorized I'm redirecting that user to login page.

Comment: With that I get this error in my console: `POST http://localhost:3000/celebrities/2/follow 401 (Unauthorized)`

Comment: Please try now ! I had xhr in caps.

Comment: can you try this: alert(xhr.status); before if condition. What are you getting?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66679/discussion-between-sachin-prasad-and-carl-edwards).